# Apach poi Excel write() takes too much time

Tags: apache-poi

I am building excel (xlsx) using POI 4.0. Below is the final code to flush and close excel workbook which takes around 4 sec on my macbook pro for aprox 900Kb on disc (actual .xlsx file). Is there any way to improve it?

Also, I am not writing huge data. Actually opening existing excel which has functions and some static content, adding a header row with cell style (around 60 columns) and then closing it.

Tried using `SXSSFWorkbook` but no improvement.
Tried to replace `FileOutputStream` with `ByteArrayOutputStream` (just to test performance) but its pretty much same.

```
public void generateFinalExcelFile(XSSFWorkbook workbook) throws IOException {
    String filePath = "somepath.xlsx"
    File outFile = new File(filePath);
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);

    workbook.write(out);  // this one takes long time.

    out.close();
    workbook.close();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried giving the `JVM` more heap size using `-Xmx<size>` option? Current max heap size used you can get using `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()`.

Comment: Are you auto-sizing any columns when you style your headers? That can be slow

Comment: @AxelRichter I have xmx set to 4G

Comment: @Gagravarr : I do not have auto sizing. But I do size absolute value. I also have various name created.